# Windows Defender/Security deletes my "hello world" program

Tags: c, windows, gcc, windows-defender

I'm trying to start a new C project using [BearLibTerminal](http://foo.wyrd.name/en:bearlibterminal), compiling with gcc.

I'm able to compile the hello world, but when I try to launch, Windows Security gives an error, which reads

> "Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a
> virus or potentially unwanted software."

Shortly after compilation, whether I attempt to run or not Windows deletes the executable.

I can of course disable Windows Security real-time protection, but this seems like a bad workaround. Does anyone know what could be changed so that Windows doesn't think my program is a virus?

Here is the code:

```
#include "BearLibTerminal.h"

int main()
{
    terminal_open();
    
    // Printing text
    terminal_print(1, 1, "Hello, world!");
    terminal_refresh();
    
    // Wait until user close the window
    while (terminal_read() != TK_CLOSE);
    
    terminal_close();
}
```

and this is the makefile:

```
gcc -IC:/foo/include -LC:/foo/bin main.c -lBearLibTerminal -o test.exe
```

Thanks kindly for the assistance.

EDIT: I seem to have fixed the problem. For some reason, the version of MinGW found [here](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/), which is where I was directed to from mingw.org, causes things I compile to be detected as a virus. I removed MinGW completely, and downloaded the version found on SourceForge, and I no longer have the issue. I have no idea if the compiler was somehow compromised, or if Windows Security was just looking out for things made by a specific version of MinGW, but I would note that the version of "Hello World" from the first compiler was 4kb larger than the version from the SourceForge compiler, and likewise the installer was around 6kb larger too.

Comment: I'd say that you should open an issue on https://github.com/cfyzium/bearlibterminal but don't have too high hopes. It has not been updated for years.

Comment: You can disable windows defender for some directories.

Comment: What happens when you use a usual "hello, world!" program like `#include <stdio.h> int main (void) {printf("hello world!";}` or just a foo program like `int main (void) {return 0;}`? Maybe it reacts to the terminal calls.

Comment: Can't you tell Windows Defender to leave the _specific_ program alone?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio , a normal "hello world" world program also gives me the same issue. This is not something I expected, because like a week ago this didn't happen.

Comment: And you didn't changed anything at WD in this week at all? Didn't installed any other tools regarding security?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio not that I know of. I may have updated windows. Since my last response I've also uninstalled and reinstalled MinGW, no change.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix you can exclude your compilation folder from Windows Defender.